# SNMP OID to get multicast bytes

Tags: snmp, multicast, oid

Right now I can only find oid for ifInMulticastPkts and ifOutMulticastPkts, but there is no bytes information. Can anyone know about this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: SNMP is generally vendor and equipment specific. What kind of device are you trying to get this info from?

Comment: I am using switch device like Dell and Cisco.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized MIB that reports this at the moment, unfortunately.  I realize that's not an answer you want though :-(